# How to check if a set of object contains object with a particular attribute

Tags: java, object, collections, set, hashset

Please look at the do while loop, I think the comment is self explanatory.
I want to check if the set contains all the cards having symbol a,b,c,d (implementing it with help of array or anything else).

```
public class Experiment2_1 {
    
    public class Card {
        char symbol;
        int number;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Card> CardSet=new HashSet<>();
        char[] array= {'a','b','c','d'};        

        do {
            Card card=new Experiment2_1().new Card();           
            System.out.println("\nEnter a card Symbol: ");
            card.symbol=sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("\nEnter card number: ");
            card.number=sc.nextInt();
            CardSet.add(card);      
        } while(!CardSet.contains(array) /*The all elements a,b,c,d (of the array) are not present as symbol of cards. All four cards Found?*/);
        
        System.out.println("All four cards were found");
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues related to you `Card` class and its usage:

- Don't break Encapsulation, use access modifiers to protect class members, and getters to expose information. Make use of parameterized constructors and void using setters when you don't need them.
- As the rule of thumb, when you're storing instances of a class in a hash-based collection, your class should have a proper implementation of the `equals/hashCode` contact.
- To avoid creating the instance of the enclosing class, you can mark nested class `Card` as `static`.

That's how class `Card` might look like:

```
public static class Card {
    private char symbol;
    private int number;
    
    public Card(char symbol, int number) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Card card = (Card) o;
        return symbol == card.symbol && number == card.number;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(symbol, number);
    }

    // getters, etc.
}
```

To find out whether all characters `'a','b','c','d'` have been used as attributes of `Card` instances, you can create a `Set` containing those characters and track all *symbols* used in your cards by storing them into another set of characters.

At the beginning of each iteration, you can verify if the *set of symbols* contains all the required characters or not using method [`Set.containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<>();
        
Set<Character> symbols = Set.of('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
Set<Character> symbolsSeen = new HashSet<>();
        
while (!symbolsSeen.containsAll(symbols)) {
            
    System.out.println("\nEnter a card Symbol: ");
    char symbol = sc.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("\nEnter card number: ");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
            
    Card card = new Card(symbol, number);
    cards.add(card);
    symbolsSeen.add(symbol);
}
```